# How do I communicate to my advisor that I would like to do more theory?

Tags: mathematics, supervision, research-topic, machine-learning

I am a PhD student working at the intersection of applied mathematics and machine learning. I'm still early in my PhD, but I'm unhappy because my current research direction is too focused on applications as opposed to theory. I consider myself a mathematician and would like to prove theorems primarily. My advisor has mostly given me projects that involve applying methods he's previously developed to new problems and is heavy in coding (which I do not enjoy very much).

I told my advisor that I wanted to do more theory, and while he seemed receptive, he hasn't offered me many options. This seems to stem from several factors:

1. He will oversell how much theoretical work there is in my current projects. He will often comment that we showed such and such, but these results are superficial.
2. He seems reluctant to offer me "hard" problems: he will sometimes discourage me from exploring something as it would be challenging to produce results.
3. I do not have a strong sense of what I would like my research direction to be and therefore am unable to come up with problems of my own: I believe that my advisor will be receptive if I come up with an impactful problem to address. I feel like I am in a chicken-and-egg situation.

I know that this is not a lack of ability on his part as he's done some very theoretical work previously and because he's advised (albeit stronger) students who have produced interesting theoretical work. I therefore have two questions:

1. How do I properly communicate these concerns, given that I have already tried to?
2. How can I learn to formulate my research direction and find problems that are both impactful and that I find interesting?

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question because your area is likely to sit between humanities (including mathematics) cultures, where the student works on their own (possibly suggested by advisor) project (with funding somewhat independent of the advisor) and the advisor gives advice, and science cultures, where the student works on the advisor's projects (with funding coming through the advisor) and the advisor supervises.  How is your department and your PhD program organized?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what sort of information you are looking for so my apologies if I'm missing the mark. I'm in a department that combines applied math and CS (including theoretical CS). As such there is a wide spectrum of people: some are very theoretical, some are very applied. In my case, the funding exclusively comes from my advisor.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you probably don't have the comparative perspective to provide useful information here.  I suppose what I want to say is that it's quite possible for an answer someone gives here to be completely off the mark because it addresses a different culture than the one you find yourself in.  I'm not sure how you, or anyone not in your department, could tell if that's the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, your supervisor may not be the correct person if he/she has no interest in theory.  I for example work on theoretical problems and if a student was to ask for a practical problem, I would try my best to steer the student away from such a problem.  I have no interest nor an understanding of the community that has interest in such problems.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Why would you try your best to steer away from problems outside your domain to your own for a student who is interested in that domain, as it is his/her PhD? I understand that you have a responsibility as a supervisor to manage your student  (within the scope of the PhD), but in the end it is his/her PhD and you will be only the supervisor, and not someone that does your work for you within your interest. I was under the impression that the supervisor should support the student even if it does not align with your interests or require to learn new skills/ask others for help.

Comment: @Atom1667 there are many practical reasons.  For example, I need to know exactly whether a student is spending his/her time on a novel idea.   Otherwise, there is no PhD.  Say if a student found a similar idea/paper, then I need to be able to have a back-up plan.   A student does not have unlimited funds and time to complete a PhD.    There are many other reasons.

Comment: The question Alexander Woo was aiming at, which you might not know the answer to, is "Who is paying for your studies?" If it's a grant then you more or less have to do whatever the grant needs you to do, and it's a fixed project. If the money is coming from elsewhere then there might be more scope to change focus.

Answer (score 3):

You have communicated, actually, but aren't quite satisfied with the results. You can keep hammering if you think that might work, but there is another option. You are currently working toward things that are quite applied as you note yourself. If you are successful at it then it will get you a doctorate. From then on you can control your own research trajectory.

So, one option is to just finish expeditiously and then work with others who have a theoretical focus as your career progresses. There is no bar to that. In other words, work toward the long term, knowing that you may not get all you want in the short term.

Aside from that, keep a notebook of ideas that arise from your current studies, especially those with a more theoretical focus and that you can follow up on later or in spare moments now. And make connections with theoreticians along the way. You don't need to depend solely on your advisor for ideas, though you have to satisfy them about your progress.

Your career will span many (many) years. You will have many opportunities along the way to think new thoughts and pursue new pathways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've received similar advice from a friend who's encouraged me to contact people beyond my advisor. However, he was thinking of this as being a way to shape my PhD (i.e. to get what I want in the short term). 

Part of my worry about expediting my PhD is that I fear that I will be pigeonholed into the applied category and will have trouble branching out in the future, as I won't have the knowledge or vision required to tackle theoretical problems. There's also the very basic problem that I do not enjoy my work very much, which makes it hard to stay motivated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an open conversation with your supervisor. You may want to start from what you are doing now and suggest a more theoretical approach as well as a path towards a publication of the results.

I believe that you should have a good time working with your supervisor. You should "click" together. If that is not the case you may want to consider changing it.